# What is a map (group theory)?

Tags: group-theory

I have this in my lecture notes, I think it relates to mapping but I'm not sure:

$\bullet{}: G\times G\rightarrow G$

What does that actually mean? I know that for a group the binary operation has to map $G$ to $G$ so $\bullet : G \bullet G \rightarrow G$ would make sense to me, is that what it's meant to mean? And multiplication is being used as an example? Or does the $\times$ mean something different in this context?

I have a definition of a map that says $\Phi : A \rightarrow B $ is a method for associating elements of A to elements of B, which looks somewhat similar to the above. From the perspective of a physicist with no background in group theory, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, $A\times B$ denotes the couples of elements in $A$ and $B$. You could write $$A\times B=\left\{(a,b)\mid a\in A, b\in B\right\}.$$
(in principle this is not a definition, but let us not dwell on details)

A map is another name for a function in many situations. So a map $\cdot: G\times G\rightarrow G$ is simply a function that maps a couple of elements in $G$ to an element of $G$.

So indeed, the multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$ does exactly that, given two real numbers it yields another real number.

Answer (score 1):

A map is simply a function. In this case, it's saying that for all $a,b\in G$, $\bullet(a,b)\in G$.

The $\times$ there is the Cartesian product: the domain of $\bullet$ is the set of all *ordered pairs* of elements of $G$. (You may be more familiar with the example of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ - or as it's more commonly known, the "$xy$-plane".)